# AngularJS. Access form validation in sibling form

Tags: angularjs

I have two forms:

```
<div ui-view="form1">
    <form name=form1> </form>
</div>

<form name=form2> </form>
```

How can I access validation status of first form (which is in child scope) in second form? For example I need to disable 'submit' button for second form if first form is $invalid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/esddjfsc/)

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname" required />
</form>
<form name="form2">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form1.$invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

Please take also a look at the [`FormController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) and its properties you can use to check inputs/form statuses (dirty, pristine, valid, etc...).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated the question with info about the form1 which is in child scope, created by ui-router. In this case your current answer isn't working.

Comment: I don't get the problem if it's a child it inherits the parent scope. Look at this JSFiddle and change it if needed http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/a8q89myf/

Comment: I can't access child scope from parent